# audio tag doen't work in angular, 404 not found error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http-status-code-404, html5-audio

I have a .wav audio file, I'm testing with simple audio tag, but it doesn't work, it's in my app.component.html

```
<audio class="col-8" controls="">
  <source src='test.wav' type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

it gives me 404 not found error.
Here is a screenshot of firefox console

[image]

I put my test.wav file in every directory of the project to avoid path problems and avoid not found, but it didn't help!

I tried the same snippet with online wav file, it works, so I tried the audio tag in a simple html file away from the angular project, it worked, so the problem is not the audio.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your folder added to dist folder after build complete?
Try to add into assets folder, and see if that is working

Comment: I put it there and in every directory, didn't work, How can I check dist folder, I can't see it in my project structure, I'm sorry if it seems silly as I'm new to angular

Comment: Look in your `.angular-cli.json` for the `assets:[]` section and see what folder names are listed there. Put your video file in one of the listed folders and then add that folder name to your path like this: `src='foldername/test.wav'` - note NO leading slash.

Comment: I put it in assets folder, and src="assets/filename, it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**audio play in Angular 14 using folder path**

*TypeScript:*

```
playSound(){

  let audio=new Audio();
  audio.src="../assets/uploads/mixkit-positive-notification-951.wav";
  audio.load();
  audio.play();

}
```

*Html Code:*

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="playSound()">Play Sound</button>
```

Note: It's working in the Angular 14 version. you can try an angular different version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the path? I get this problem sometimes when trying to link to a file.

Example:

```
<audio class="col-8" controls>
 <source src='./test.wav/' type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

Note: You don't need to add the quotation marks after the `controls` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I put it in assets folder, and make src="assets/filename", it worked.